# How do I specify the step definition prototype name in Intellij Idea?

Tags: coding-style, intellij-idea, content-assist, cucumber-jvm

I write my cucumber scenario to include the following step:

```
And the frabjous bandersnatch whiffled "Callooh"
```

Type alt-enter, choose *Create Step Definition*, and it produces:

```
@And("^the frabjous bandersnatch whiffled \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_frabjous_bandersnatch_whiffled(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

but our coding standards require camelCase for methods, so I have to manually change `the_frabjous_bandersnatch_whiffled` to `theFrabjousBandersnatchWhiffled`.  Is there a setting somewhere that will tell Idea to use camel case instead of underscores in this situation?

Also, when it's offering possible classes into which to place my new stepdef, can I have it filter to only classes with names ending in "Steps"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably way too late, but maybe still helpful:

You can set the `--snippets camelcase` option in the Edit Configurations in intelliJ:

Main menu Run -> Edit Configurations

(I have prepared a screenshot to show this, but almighty Stackoverflow deems me unworthy of posting images, well thought out, indeed!)

Comment: Can you expand on this please, I'm not having much joy generating camelcase step definitions from features in Intellij 14, thanks.

Comment: If only Stackoverflow would allow me to post a screenshot. It is pretty straightforward: Just add --snippets camelcase to the Program arguments line.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work with IntelliJ 14 and `Cucumber for Java` plugin version 141.178.